# Dictation under macOS Catalina not working with display microphone

Tags: macos, microphone, voice-dictation

I have this very strange problem that dictation is not working on my laptop when its lid is closed and it is connected to an external monitor (Cinema display).
It does work fine when I use the laptop standalone.

Also, when I go to System Preferences / Keyboard / Dictation, I can see the microphone showing input (level meter does up and down when I speak). 
It does not matter whether the audio input under the microphone is on "Display audio" or "Automatic", when I open any other app and start dictating, the little microphone does not show any sign of activity (i.e., input).

Even more funny is that Siri on the laptop works fine, even with closed laptop lid, i.e., it does recognize my speech commands.

I think, the real problem is that, somehow, with display microphone, something is blocking the audio input on the way to the dictation software.

Of course, I have googled and tried a few things (reboot, switch audio, etc.), to no avail. But I haven't found a problem description on the web that matches the problems symptoms I am experiencing.

Does anyone have an idea?

PS:
I recently upgraded to Catalina (10.15.3). Before, under Mojave, dictation worked.

Comment: does it work if you connect, for example, AirPods to your MacBook and set AirPods as the sound input?

Comment: Good Question.  No, it doesn't work. No matter , which input source I choose in System Audio Preferences. I can choose AirPods in the System Preferences , and the input level meter shows activity, but no activity in the little microphone icon next to dictation when I double-click Fn.

Comment: yes, same for me.

Comment: Still a problem for me in 2020

Comment: Still unsolved for me (the OP) with 10.15.6

Comment: Update: Seems like this problem is solved for me in Big Sur.

Comment: Update:  Still a problem as it constantly stops working for me and I have to reboot.

Comment: Still a problem for me in 2024. Dictation will only work with Apple-made microphones. Works fine with Airpods Pro 2 but not with Logitech C920.

Comment: Me, too. My solution is to open the macbook's lid, then it will use the built-in microphone. But definitely not apple-like :-(

Answer (score 7):

Me too :-( I am on the phone with tech support now. Tech support said,

> "After doing some research it looks like this is something Apple
>   engineers are aware of and investigating. They have a suggestion to
>   consider using Voice Control as an option."

For the time being, I am using Voice Control... which isn't really a great option IMO.